# setting label value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have code like this

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBookmarksIds" Style="visibility: hidden;" Text="test"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="buttonPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnInvokeImageRead" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                                    OnClick="btnInvokeImageRead_Click" Style="visibility: hidden;" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

in javascript i'm trying to set value of label and call codebehind function so that i will have desired value passed to codebehind like that :

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%= lblBookmarksIds.ClientID%>').firstChild.nodeValue);
            document.getElementById('<%= lblBookmarksIds.ClientID%>').innerText = str;
            alert(document.getElementById('<%= lblBookmarksIds.ClientID%>').firstChild.nodeValue);
            //alert('1');
            if (str != "") {
                document.getElementById('<%= btnInvokeImageRead.ClientID%>').click();
            }
```

when second alert gets displayed the value of lblBookmarksIds has changed value, but when i debug in codebehind function btnInvokeImageRead_Click the value of lblBookmarksIds has its old value.

Anybody knows Why ?

Regards
Wojciech

Answer (score 0):

Labels are not passed to code behind. You will have to use an input(TextBox) for that purpose.

You can style an input to look like a label using CSS.

Alternatively, you can keep the value in a hidden field, and use javascript to show the value in a label and pass it back in the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

The reason ASP.NET is able to "see" the values entered into a `TextBox` and similar controls is because the values of these controls are sent in the `POST` body when the page posts back. You can see this through any number of tools, including the Developer Tools your browser likely includes or an intercepting proxy like Fiddler. When the postback occurs, each of those controls has a `LoadPostData` function that processes the `POST` data and updates the `Text` properties (or whatever properties) of the control.

The contents of a `Label` are not submitted in the `POST` data, so .NET has no way to see any changes made to it from JavaScript.

The controls that do process post data all implement [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx).